# Multi bin packing

Tags: library, optimization, algorithms

I need a library or software (free or paid) to do multi bin packing:

Inputs:

- several boxes (WxHxD) and their weight
- several containers (WxHxD) and their maximum weight

Output:

- minimum number of containers required to pack all of the items and how should the items be placed inside them

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which OS and which programming language?

Comment: @ThomasWeller possibly Windows, C++ or C would be great for the language but I have no preference (I can link to anything)

Comment: Linking to .NET from C++ is e.g. not trivial. It also includes many dependencies. Same for Java. Similar for Python: you might not want to bring a Python interpreter into your project.